# JSON.parse get values

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, response

I need to check one value from JSON response before continuing the script, but it doesn't work.

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "addproduct.php",
    data: {productId : selectedValue, customerId : customerId},
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        if(response === undefined) {
            alert("undefined");
        } else if (response.pricelistupdate = 1) { //this doesn't work
            alert("ERROR! Adding a product is denied");
        } else {
            orderAddRow(response);
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("ERROR");
    }
});
```

I'm getting following JSON response:

```
{"row":{"pricelistupdate":0,"ID":"000017","name":"Chair","discount":"0.00","price":"0.00"}}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: remove line `response = JSON.parse(response);`, because you already added `datatype: "json",`

Comment: It should also be `response.row.pricelistupdate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What errors did i see:

1. You don't need the `JSON.parse()` as `datatype:"json"` is there.
2. Reference to the `pricelistupdate` should be `response.row.pricelistupdate`.
3. Instead of comparing `===` to a value you are assigning it `=` in the `elseif`.

---

As you have a `dataType`:

```
datatype: "json",
```

so you don't need to parse the json then. you can remove it `response = JSON.parse(response);`.

`JSON.parse()` method should only be used on a json string but in your case the response is a valid json so you don't need it.

and just get it:

You need to refer to your object keys and you are missing the key `row` and you have also missed  `=` equal sign in the `elseif` :

```
else if (response.row.pricelistupdate === 1)
```

---

So it has to be something like this in your success callback:

```
success: function (response) {
    if(response === undefined) {
        alert("undefined");
    } else if (response.row.pricelistupdate === 1) { // check "===" equals
        alert("ERROR! Adding a product is denied");
    } else {
        orderAddRow(response);
    }
},
```

Comment: But it causes no error having it there? Problem is somewhere in `response.pricelistupdate = 1`

Comment: check the update i guess you have missed the `===` operator in your else if.

Comment: Ok, I corrected the `===` operator, but console says that `response.row` is undefined.

Comment: @lingo then you don't have row in your json.

Comment: Yes I have. I got it to work by adding `response.row.pricelistupdate` and leaving `response = JSON.parse(response)` on its place.

Comment: great! but there is one thing, the response would be a json string that is why it is working with putting `JSON.parse()`. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

@jai is right since your response type is json so your "response" variable is already contains json so first of all remove

```
 response = JSON.parse(response);
```

seeing at your response, your response is stored in row object so you are accessing "pricelistupdate" incorrectly you should replace it with response.row.pricelistupdate so your final code looks like

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "addproduct.php",
    data: {productId : selectedValue, customerId : customerId},
    datatype: "json",
    success: function (response) {
        if(response === undefined) {
            alert("undefined");
        } else if (response.row.pricelistupdate = 1) { 
            alert("ERROR! Adding a product is denied");
        } else {
            orderAddRow(response.row);
        }
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("ERROR");
    }
});
```